# Cannot set ImageSource using pack URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to set an image source using the pack uri like this:

```
<Setter.Value>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/grid_bg.png"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

**with a Resources.resx file like this:**

[image]

**with the image in it like this:**

[image]

**but the error I get is this:**

[image: kill me now]

I have also attempted this:

[Pack URI and path not resolving image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874705/pack-uri-and-path-not-resolving-image-in-wpf)

and this:

[At design time pack uri is valid, but not at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836039/at-design-time-pack-uri-is-valid-but-not-at-runtime)

and this:

http://csharpsimplified.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/resources-in-wpf-i-binary-resources/

while still getting the same error as above.  Somebody, please, for the love of zeus, liberate me from this menial, frustrating garbage and I will return the favor with praise and points.

Comment: does grid_pg have the correct access modifier?

Comment: internal? public? no code generation?  all of them fail.  :/

Comment: I have also tried to have them linked at compile time and embedded into the .resx file - no luck there either.

Comment: Is your Resource file .png inside a "Resources" folder in the current project and I think you should also include your assembly name in the pack uri?

Comment: Yes sir/maam -> http://i.imgur.com/WXhFE7s.png

Comment: I am able to access it programatically as well using [project_name].Resources.grid_bg

Comment: If your resource file is in local project, you should be able to use: ImageSource="../../Resources/grid_bg.png" instead of a pack uri syntax..

Comment: Can you pls also check that Build Action for file /Resources/grid_bg.png is "Resource"... for using pack uri syntax..

Comment: Is is currently set to Resource.  I should note that I have currently defined a ResourceDictionary in Application.Resources in App.xaml to define a styling template for some UI elements.  Does this have anything to do with it?  I just find it so puzzling that I can access it from the .cs by not from the App.xaml ...

Comment: I should also note that when I feed it the full path from disk, it works correctly as well. (ex:  ImageSource="C:\path\to\button_bg.png" )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a WPF project you usually do not add image files as resources to Resource.resx. Instead you just put them into a folder in your project and set their Build Action to `Resource`, as shown below.

[image]

It is also not necessary to write the Pack URI prefix. You can just write it like this:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/grid_bg.png"/>
```

---

Please note that if you add images to Resource.resx, Visual Studio generates a `Resources` class with static properties for each image. These properties are of type `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which is WinForms, not WPF.